# what is difference Three-way operator( ~ ? a: b). and Alternative operator. in my code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, operator-keyword, loader

```
<>
   {isLoading || <Loader />}
   <iframe
     ref={iframeRef}
     title="title"
     src={src}
     onLoad={onIframeLoad}
   />
</>
```

I wrote the code like this at first.
this code is in react and with
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
and In the onIframeLoad func With other works, i doing setIsLoading(false)

so i think loader component i cant see
but i can see iframe with loader
???

so i changed the code    {isLoading || } => {isLoading ?  : ''}
then it work well

but i dont understand what is difference code meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Loader />` component will be visible when `isLoading` is `false` in your code.

`{isLoading || <Loader />}` should be `{isLoading && <Loader />}`.

```
<>
   {isLoading && <Loader />}
   <iframe
     ref={iframeRef}
     title="title"
     src={src}
     onLoad={onIframeLoad}
   />
</>
```

Comment: oh my godㅜㅜ i Confused it. Thank you for answering my question.